# Dropping a commit in git rebase -i does not reduce the size of .git folder

Tags: git

I have a git repository where the `.git` folder is **7MB**. I have then added and committed an .exe file that is **16MB** followed by:

```
git gc --aggressive && git prune
```

After the above my `.git` folder is now **23MB**.

Next I have done a `git rebase -i` and selected *drop*:

[image]

on the commit (**c8185ff**) that introduced the 16MB file, I completed the rebase and again ran:

```
git gc --aggressive && git prune
```

Now when I measure the `.git` folder its still **23MB**.

Should `git rebase` performed above not remove the commit completely from history - as if the file was never introduced - and hence bring the `.git` folder back to the **7MB** size?

I also tried to do a fresh clone of the repository and the size is still **23MB** - I assume the reflog will be cleared when doing a fresh clone.

Comment: I suspect that commit is still reachable from the reflog.

Comment: The large .exe file was introduced in c8185ff, it did not exists before.

Comment: I removed my answer, after doing a test I see rebase rewrites the tree and proves my theory incorrect.

Comment: Couldn't you put the code that generates this exe, instead of adding it directly to git? I don't think it is a good idea to put binaries on repositories...

Comment: Fully agree binaries should not be committed, but this post is purely meant to understand how re-writes of history in git works with git rebase -i, e.g. for when the accident have occurred. And also be able to verify that the  clean-up was indeed successful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, `git gc` only prune **loose** objects older than 2 weeks.

To force a prune on all objects, use [`--prune=all`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-gc#git-gc---pruneltdategt):

```
git -c gc.reflogExpire=now gc --prune=all
```

But, if the object is still reachable through any reference (remote one like `origin/master` for example, or the reflog), it won't be pruned.

That's why we have to also set the [`gc.reflogExpire`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-gcreflogExpire) configuration to `now`.

(For `git prune` [not necessary after a gc], it's [`--expire`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-prune#git-prune---expirelttimegt))

Comment: When I do the above on the original repository .git is still 23MB. If I clone it to a new location .git folder is still 23MB but if I then run 'git gc --prune=all' then it gets down to the original 7MB. Also tried with 'git prune --expire now' on original repository but seems I need to do it on a fresh clone to see the effect/verify that it no longer exists in history.

Comment: I fixed my answer to also clean the reflog.